# Residue on branch cut?

Tags: complex-analysis

My question essentially is

> How is the ‘residue’ on branch cut defined?

You may immediately say, there is no Laurent series about points on branch cut, so no residue is definable. QED

Ya...but what if the residue is defined as
$$\int^{2\pi+\alpha}_{\alpha}f(q+re^{it})ire^{it}dt$$ where $q$ is a point on the branch cut (not branch point) of $f$?

What are the procedures to evaluate the integral in general?

In case there is no general form, how about this?
$$\int^{2\pi+\alpha}_{\alpha}f(q+re^{it})\ln(p+re^{it})ire^{it}dt$$ ($f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb C$ and is not analytic at $q$, $q$ is a point on the branch cut of $\ln$)

Comment: See if this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545083/what-happens-to-poles-lying-on-branch-cuts-in-contour-integration/1545490#1545490

Answer (score 1):

I tried an example.  The function $\sqrt{z}$ at the point $z=-1$.  Branch cut on the negative real axis.  As suggested, let
$$
\phi(r) := \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{-1+re^{it}} i r e^{it}\;dt
$$
For example,
$$
\phi(1/2) = i\;\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}-\sqrt{6}\right) .
$$
It is purely imaginary.  Here is the graph of $\mathrm{Im}\big(\phi(r)\big)$ for $0<r<1$:

[image: graph]

I do not expect this to be useful for anything, though.

Comment: Thank you. How about the second case?